# Assert that a Array of JSONs contains one property

Tags: javascript, postman, chai, web-api-testing

I have a device store project that allows to add/delete/edit devices and I'm trying to test in postman that after a POST ,that adds a device to the list ,the device can be found in my response body.I'm using Postman BDD and the Chai sintax

```
[
{
    "deviceid": "5a72fec0-a220-4484-a058-e1e56dfc56c5",
    "name": "Huawei",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 200,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "90807800-c66c-46ec-ae46-687464e62797",
    "name": "Pixel 2",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 300,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "c2bd507d-e544-4ce8-b272-34cab732adb4",
    "name": "SONYk",
    "alias": "electronicsm",
    "quantity": 122,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "caa97d05-2672-48c5-8c56-e0da1298b20d",
    "name": "ASUS1",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 1222,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "11535983-b9d0-4a0f-8d53-ca204446e0b8",
    "links": []
}
```

]

This is my response , as it can be seen it return a Array of JSONs and I'm looking for an elegant way to assert that the device with the property "Pixel 2" is in the Array. I'm open to any other javascript librarys that can help me achieve this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` method which accepts a **callback** provided function.

```js
var array=[
{
    "deviceid": "5a72fec0-a220-4484-a058-e1e56dfc56c5",
    "name": "Huawei",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 200,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "90807800-c66c-46ec-ae46-687464e62797",
    "name": "Pixel 2",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 300,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "c2bd507d-e544-4ce8-b272-34cab732adb4",
    "name": "SONYk",
    "alias": "electronicsm",
    "quantity": 122,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "caa97d05-2672-48c5-8c56-e0da1298b20d",
    "name": "ASUS1",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 1222,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "11535983-b9d0-4a0f-8d53-ca204446e0b8",
    "links": []
}];
var item=array.find(function(item){
  return item.name=="Pixel 2";
});
console.log(item);
console.log("Exists: "+item!=undefined);
```

Another method is to use `includes` function.

```js
var array=[
{
    "deviceid": "5a72fec0-a220-4484-a058-e1e56dfc56c5",
    "name": "Huawei",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 200,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "90807800-c66c-46ec-ae46-687464e62797",
    "name": "Pixel 2",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 300,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "c2bd507d-e544-4ce8-b272-34cab732adb4",
    "name": "SONYk",
    "alias": "electronicsm",
    "quantity": 122,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "caa97d05-2672-48c5-8c56-e0da1298b20d",
    "name": "ASUS1",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 1222,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "11535983-b9d0-4a0f-8d53-ca204446e0b8",
    "links": []
}];
var exists=array.map(function(item){
  return item.name;
}).includes("Pixel 2");
console.log(exists);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
response.some( o => o.name == "Pixel 2" )
```

The result is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

No  library needed. You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
if (response.some(i => i.name == 'Pixel 2')) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7-LesvaHVAhXJvBoKHcOpDzsQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHTybPLK3GeAl_0DVx-FLbAD2mWtw) with [`Array#length`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjw29G7vaHVAhWJ0RoKHSdnCjkQFggzMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Flength&usg=AFQjCNH2BeItW8LUd08jsGITkmYmotCJCw) to find if your item exists

```js
const array = [{
        "deviceid": "5a72fec0-a220-4484-a058-e1e56dfc56c5",
        "name": "Huawei",
        "alias": "electronics",
        "quantity": 10,
        "price": 200,
        "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
        "links": []
    },
    {
        "deviceid": "90807800-c66c-46ec-ae46-687464e62797",
        "name": "Pixel 2",
        "alias": "electronics",
        "quantity": 10,
        "price": 300,
        "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
        "links": []
    },
    {
        "deviceid": "c2bd507d-e544-4ce8-b272-34cab732adb4",
        "name": "SONYk",
        "alias": "electronicsm",
        "quantity": 122,
        "price": 2222,
        "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
        "links": []
    },
    {
        "deviceid": "caa97d05-2672-48c5-8c56-e0da1298b20d",
        "name": "ASUS1",
        "alias": "electronics",
        "quantity": 1222,
        "price": 2222,
        "categoryid": "11535983-b9d0-4a0f-8d53-ca204446e0b8",
        "links": []
    }
];

const hasPixel2 = array.filter(item => item.name === 'Pixel 2').length > 0;
console.log(hasPixel2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `Array#Filter`

```js
var array=[
{
    "deviceid": "5a72fec0-a220-4484-a058-e1e56dfc56c5",
    "name": "Huawei",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 200,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "90807800-c66c-46ec-ae46-687464e62797",
    "name": "Pixel 2",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 10,
    "price": 300,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "c2bd507d-e544-4ce8-b272-34cab732adb4",
    "name": "SONYk",
    "alias": "electronicsm",
    "quantity": 122,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "91a71dc0-4d40-4d20-a59d-bb30a348a7f2",
    "links": []
},
{
    "deviceid": "caa97d05-2672-48c5-8c56-e0da1298b20d",
    "name": "ASUS1",
    "alias": "electronics",
    "quantity": 1222,
    "price": 2222,
    "categoryid": "11535983-b9d0-4a0f-8d53-ca204446e0b8",
    "links": []
}];
var item = array.filter(item => item.name === "Pixel 2");
console.log(item);
```